# How to associate a function with a metabox button?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, meta-boxes

I'm setting up a site for a client in Wordpress using X-Pro and need to add a metabox button to our Woocommerce product pages so that the client can associate downloadable PDFs with each product. Ideally, this will sit at the bottom of a post alongside or below the current 'Contact us' button.

[Image of contact page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDTtF.png)

I'm a coding newbie, so used metabox.io to generate some code for me to add the button to my backend:

```
function add_pdf_btn( $meta_boxes ) {
    $prefix = 'mcc-';

    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'id' => 'uploadpdf',
        'title' => esc_html__( 'Upload PDF', 'mcc-online-generator' ),
        'post_types' => array('product' ),
        'context' => 'after_editor',
        'priority' => 'default',
        'autosave' => 'false',
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'id' => $prefix . 'product_pdf',
                'type' => 'button',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Upload PDF file', 'mcc-online-generator' ),
                'desc' => esc_html__( 'Upload any PDF file associated with the product here', 'mcc-online-generator' ),
                'mime_type' => 'application/pdf',
                'max_file_uploads' => 5,
                'max_status' => 'true',
                'size' => 5,
                // Button text.
                'std' => 'Upload PDF',
            ),
        ),
    );

    return $meta_boxes;
    }
    add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'add_pdf_btn' );
```

This generates the button just fine, but I need to associate a function with that button and I've no idea how to do that. Hope I've explained myself clearly.

Comment: You can use jquery to attach an event to the button just like normal

Comment: WooCommerce already has this built-in. If you click the "downloadable" checkbox when editing the product you can upload any type of file, including PDFs, that will be made available to the customer after purchase. It's meant more for selling digital downloads, but can also be used to give access to, for example, manuals. See WC instructions [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/digital-downloadable-product-handling/)